# java.io.IOException: Error decoding PKCS 12 input" while creating GoogleCredential object

Tags: java, google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-firebase

While creating credential object, it fails with error "java.io.IOException: Error decoding PKCS 12 input" when it tries to set private key from p12:

```
InputStream content = ..... // logic to get input stream  
File file = new File("Analytics-data-retrieval.p12");  
FileUtils.copyInputStreamToFile(content, file);

GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder()
            .setTransport(httpTransport)
            .setJsonFactory(JSON_FACTORY)
            .setServiceAccountId(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL)
            .setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File(file)
            .setServiceAccountScopes(AnalyticsReportingScopes.all())
            .build();
```

Comment: What is `file`? Show some more code on how you get `file`.

Comment: @VHS - Sorry about providing incomplete information..I have updated the code in the description.

Comment: I think the file `Analytics-data-retrieval.p12` is not readable. That's why the method `setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File` throws an IOException. Can you check the return value of `file.canRead()`? If it is false, that's the reason for your IOException.

Comment: @VHS - I tried your suggestion and it returns true. So, the read permission seems to be there. Also, I verified that the new file "Analytics-data-retrieval.p12" is having the required data. Any additional suggestions?..Thank you.